# Why would I ever want to make cookies?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I can make bread for practically the same amount of wheat?

Minecraft 1.4 is out now, which includes Cookies. 2 wheat and the extremely rare cocoa beans makes a stack of 8 cookies, healing .5 hearts each.

On the other hand, 3 wheat produces one bread that heals 2.5 hearts. Given that a stack of cookies heals less than a stack of bread, why would I ever want to bake cookies in the first place, especially given the extremely limited quality of cocoa beans (I've found a grand total of *one* dungeon so far).

Heck, if cows are around, I can even turn the 3 wheat for bread into a cake, which has an even greater total health recovery over cookies.

So what's the point of cookies at all?

Comment: It gives the game more flavor(s).

Comment: Why would anyone *not* want to eat cookies? I think I'll grab some right now.

Comment: This is similar to apples as they can only be found in dungeons as well

Comment: What's the point of Minecraft? I could spend all these hours making actual cookies!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, .5 * 8 = 4, so that's more than the 2.5 hearts from wheat. Of course, if you used the same amount of wheat, 6, then that'd be 12 for the cookies, and 5 for the bread. Also, sometimes it can be advantageous to not use all of your life giving at once, which bread does.

Comment: The main takeaway is that your health-per-wheat is better with cookies than it is with bread (provided you have the beans).

Comment: Oh, wow. I guess you can tell you've spent too much time working on code and your brain is fried when even simple math fails you.

Comment: @Raven: LOL, no worries, it happens to the best of us:-) Nice to be able to help with a game I've never even heard of:-)

Comment: you *should* go try Minecraft - assuming you don't mind losing hours of productivity a day, anyway. :)

Answer (score 10):

Because the main objective of Minecraft is to have **fun**.

And sometimes fun is to do things just because you want to do them, and because you can do them. You don't need to be extremely efficient to have fun.

You can imagine a game that allows you to make an item that heals you; or you can imagine a game that allows you to make cakes, bread and cookies. And, hey, it doesn't even matter if it heals me or not, I can make cookies in a game! How awesome is that?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are used to make tamed wolves sit down

Comment: yes, but they're not exclusive in that.

Comment: Tamed wolves sit down when you right-click on them. The item doesn't matter other than that it needs to not be wolf food (or a bow).